# Регулярное выражение, убрать пробелы

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Вот таким регулярным выражением удаляю все символы кроме цифр в строке

```
value.replace(/(?!-)[^0-9.]/g, ' ')
```

как в месте этим (в одном регулярном выражении), удалить еще и все пробелы?

Comment: вместо `' '` поставьте `''`

Comment: если убираю пробел, то регулярна не работает

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/dJW7An/2

Comment: Проще нужно быть, проще: `/[^0-9.-]+/g`

Comment: Вопрос неясен, пожалуйста, добавьте неработающий код в вопрос. [`value = value.replace(/[^0-9.-]+/g, '')`](https://jsfiddle.net/Lxr2m2dL/1/) прекрасно работает и отвечает вашим требованиям.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так:

```
var rez = x.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
```

Обращаем внимание что в условии сказано цифр а не чисел.

0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 это цифры, а -345 и 34.444 это числа. С числами это уже другая задача.

Код на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abzjwhd9/).

Comment: не работает это.

Comment: на jsfiddle работает, возможно вы как-то не так запускаете, или ошибка в другом месте. А что именно не работает?